# How to GroupBy List<Dictionary<string,ClassName>> by class ClassName property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dynamic

I want to group by my list of dictionaries dynamically just like:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, ClassName>> GroupBy(this List<Dictionary<string, ClassName>> list)
{
    return list.AsQueryable().GroupBy(i => new { Key1 = i["Key01"].ClassProperty, Key2 = i["Key02"].AnotherClassProperty });
}
```

but I need to set keys name and numbers dynamically.
I had an idea to create dynamic-typed variable using ExpandoObject like that:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, ClassName>> GroupBy(this List<Dictionary<string, ClassName>> list, IEnumerable<string> fieldnames)
{
    
return list.AsQueryable().GroupBy(i => GetKeys(fieldnames, dict) });

dynamic GetKeys(IEnumerable<string> fieldnames, Dictionary<string, ClassName> dict) 
{
    IDictionary<string, object> sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var fieldname in fieldnames)
    {
        sampleObject.Add($"Key{sampleObject.Count}", dict.GetValueOrDefault(fieldname).ClassProperty;
    }
    return sampleObject;
}
```

}

Comment: Use SelectMany :             var group = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y)).GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToList();

Comment: Can please elaborate what do you want to achieve this code?

Comment: Why do you have `AsQueryable()` in your code?

Comment: Your sample code for `GroupBy` doesn't have a return type that matches LINQ `GroupBy` - what do you expect to return?